# Finding the general formula for a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I wanna find the general formula for the sequence below:
$$
U(n+2)=U(n+1)/(n+2)+nU(n)/(n+2).$$

I know how the Fibonacci sequence is derived either by linear algebra or some other method but I can't, how can I derive this?
With the initial conditions  U0=U1=1

Comment: Are there any initial conditions?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information about how to display math properly on this site.  It is also customary to include information about what you have tried when asking a question here.

Comment: Is it$$u_{n+2}=\frac{u_{n+1}}{n+2}+\frac{nu_n}{n+2}$$?

Comment: Might help to define $a_n=nU_n$, whence $a_{n+2}=\frac {a_{n+1}}{n+1}+a_n$.

Comment: Maybe it means $u_{n+2}=\frac{(n+1)u_{n+1}}{n+2}+\frac{nu_n}{n+2}?$ If so, use Fibonacci.

Comment: U0=U1=1 And the  sequence is as Dr. Sonnhard graubner wrote it

Comment: Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: The OGF for $U(n)$ is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty U(n)z^n = \sqrt{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}$ This implies $U(n) = f(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor)$ where $f(k) = \frac{\binom{2k}{k}}{4^{k}}$.

Comment: @achillehui Could you show how to get that in an answer please?  I've been trying to do it, but I keep messing it up.

Comment: I got no solution as the answer ! Am i right ?

Comment: @saulspatz 1) Multiply both sides by $(n+2) z^n$ and start to sum from $n = 0$.
2) Define $U(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty U(n)z^n$ and express above sum in terms of $U(z)$ and it's derivative. In particular use the trick: if $g(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty g_k z^k$, then $zg'(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty kg_k z^k$. At the end,we get an ODE in $U(z)$ which is very simple to solve....

Comment: @learningstudent No, of course there's a solution.  We have $u_0, u_1$ given, and a formula to produce $u_{n+2}$ from $u_n$ and $u_{n+1}$, so that the sequence $u$ is completely determined.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks, I'll try that.  I was missing the first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(n+2)U_{n+2}=U_{n+1}+nU_n$$
The generating function for this sequence is
$$f(z)=U_0+U_1z+U_2z^2+U_3z^3+\dots$$
Hence we have
$$f'(z)=U_1+2U_2z+3U_3z^2+\dots$$
$$z^2f'(z)=U_1z^2+2U_2z^3+3U_3z^4+\dots$$
$$f'(z)-z^2f'(z)=U_1+2U_2z+(3U_3-U_1)z^2+(4U_4-2U_2)z^3+\dots$$
So applying $U_{n+1}=(n+2)U_{n+2}-nU_n$ and factoring gives
$$(1-z^2)f'(z)=U_1+2U_2z+U_2z^2+U_3z^3+\dots$$
$$(1-z^2)f'(z)=U_1+2U_2z+f(z)-U_0-U_1z$$
$$(1-z^2)f'(z)-f(z)=U_1-U_0+(2U_2-U_1)z$$
We have that $2U_2=U_1+0U_0$ hence $U_0=U_1=1$ and $U_2=\frac12$ which gives
$$(1-z^2)f'(z)-f(z)=1-1+\left(2\left(\frac12\right)-1\right)z=0$$
$$f'(z)=\frac{f(z)}{1-z^2}$$
$$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac1{1-z^2}$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\ln{(f(z))}=\frac1{1-z^2}$$
$$\ln{(f(z))}=\int\frac1{1-z^2}\mathrm{d}z$$
$$\ln{(f(z))}=\ln{\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}\right)}$$
$$\therefore f(z)=\sqrt{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}$$
As suggested by @achille hui this gives
$$U_n=4^{-\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{2\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$$
or equivalently,
$$U_n=\frac{(2\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1)!!}{2^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\lfloor n/2\rfloor!}$$
where $n!!$ denotes the double-factorial function.

Comment: Please give some indication of how to get the power series of $f(z)$.  I can't seem to do anything today.

Comment: It equivalent to $(1+z)(1-z^2)^{-1/2}$ so you can use binomial expansion on the right term and then add adjacent terms together in order to multiply by the $1+z$ factor.

Comment: Thank you.  Today seems to be one long senior moment.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the generating function method explained by Peter Foreman and Achille Hui.  Unfortunately, my brain seems to be on strike today, and I couldn't make it come out.  I solved the problem with an ad hoc method that I was ashamed to post at first, but on reflection, I think it may be of interest.

I started by computing a few values of the sequence and I got

```
0 1  
1 1
2 1/2
3 1/2
4 3/8
5 3/8
6 5/16
7 5/16
8 35/128
9 35/128
10 63/256
11 63/256
12 231/1024
13 231/1024
14 429/2048
15 429/2048
16 6435/32768
17 6435/32768
18 12155/65536
19 12155/65536
20 46189/262144
21 46189/262144
```

It's an obvious guess that $u_{2n+1}=u_{2n}$ so assuming this is true, and letting $v_m=u_{2m}$ I got $$ v_{m+1}={2m+1\over2m+2}v_m,\ v_0=1$$ so that
$$u_{2m}=v_m=1\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac34\cdot\frac56\cdot\cdots\cdot{2m-1\over2m}={(2m-1)!!\over(2m)!!}$$

Of course, one still has to verify that the original guess $u_{2n+1}=u_{2n}$ holds in general.